# Why OpenCV 4.5.2 doesn't have apps built

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I installed OpenCV 4.5.2 using the Windows installer and when I looked in the apps folder, I couldn't find some apps (create_samples, train_cascade). So, I downloaded the code and I generated visual studio projects using CMake. After I built all those project, again, in the app folder there were no project files to build those apps.
I also run `cmake .`  in an app directory, but this error came out:

```
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (ocv_add_application):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_add_application".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/opencv/opencv-master/apps/createsamples/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

this is the CMakeLists.txt file that I run:

```
file(GLOB SRCS *.cpp)


ocv_add_application(opencv_createsamples
    MODULES opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_objdetect opencv_imgcodecs opencv_highgui opencv_calib3d opencv_features2d opencv_videoio
    SRCS ${SRCS})
```

In all honesty, last time that I used CMake was 10 years ago and I really would like an hand to figure this out.
Thanks

**STACK:**

```
CMake  3.20.3
OpenCV 4.5.2
Python 3.9.5
Visual Studio 16.10.0
Wndows 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why this is happening. In opencv 4.5 (I didn't check other versions), the line in the cmake file that generate the solution for traincascade and createsamples, are explicitly commented out. This because building those apps will generate more than 600 errors! Let's hope this problem will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231

> These apps has been disabled during legacy C API removal. Rewriting them
> with C++ API was not an option because it is too easy to break them
> and hard to test.
>
> Also modern approaches via DNN provides much better results - just
> compare OpenCV face detector with CascadeClassifier and DNN.